# faster way to do this table transformation in R

Tags: r

I have a simple table of stock prices, let's call it "price," with tickers along the top and dates along the side.

I want to create a new table, "price_norm," which divides every price by the first one. So for example, the first column might look like:

```
price     price_norm
20.00     1.000
21.00     1.050
21.00     1.050
20.00     1.000
20.50     1.025
```

...etc

The wrinkle is that some stocks don't have pricing all the way back to the first date, so their column in "price" begins with a string of NAs -- in that case they should be divided by the first non-NA value, not the value in the first row.

There may also be a few stocks with no price at all, where every value is NA; in this case the corresponding column in price_norm should be all NA too.

I have done this in a way that works but very slowly -- 30 seconds or more to process. I'm looking for a more efficient way:

```
price_norm <- price

nonNAIndex <- function(z) {
  min(which(!is.na(z)))
}

for( j in colnames(price) ) {

  if(!is.na(price[nrow(price),j])) {  

    k <- nonNAIndex(price[,j])

    for( i in k:nrow(price) ) {
      price_norm[i,j] <- ( price[i,j] / price[k,j] ) 
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following sounds like it should do what you want:

```
## sample data
mydf <- data.frame(v1 = c(20.00, 21.00, 21.00, 20.00, 20.50), 
                   v2 = c(NA, 20.00, 21.00, 21.00, 20.00),
                   v3 = NA)

mydf / lapply(mydf, function(x) ifelse(all(is.na(x)), NA, na.omit(x)[1]))
#      v1   v2 v3
# 1 1.000   NA NA
# 2 1.050 1.00 NA
# 3 1.050 1.05 NA
# 4 1.000 1.05 NA
# 5 1.025 1.00 NA
```

I've just created a list of the initial values and divided the original `data.frame` by those values.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your data is a `data.frame`

```
sapply(df, function(x) {x/ifelse(all(is.na(x)), NA, head(x[!is.na(x)],1))})
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could try: (Using @Ananda Mahto's dataset)

```
m1 <- t(mydf)
mydf/as.list(m1[cbind(1:nrow(m1),max.col(!is.na(m1), "first"))])
```

#### Benchmarks

On a slightly bigger dataset

```
set.seed(24)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(NA,1:25), 1e3*2e3, replace=TRUE), ncol=2e3))
f1 <- function() df/lapply(df, function(x) ifelse(all(is.na(x)), NA, na.omit(x)[1]))
f2 <- function() sapply(df, function(x) {x/ifelse(all(is.na(x)), NA, head(x[!is.na(x)],1))})
f3 <- function() {m1 <- t(df)
                df/as.list(m1[cbind(1:nrow(m1),max.col(!is.na(m1), "first"))])}

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(f1(), f2(), f3(), unit="relative", times=25L)
#Unit: relative
#expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
#f1() 1.213922 1.197350 1.140682 1.103249 1.351307    25
#f2() 6.318962 6.925681 7.212136 6.370824 8.080331    25
#f3() 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000    25
```